# Probability distribution problem #1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be i.i.d random variables having $\text{Poi}(\lambda)$ distribution. Put $T=X1+2\cdot X2$.
So I have to find $\mathbb{P}(X_1+2 \cdot X_2=t)$.
I can't solve this. How should I proceed.

Comment: How is $T$ an estimator for $\lambda$ (sufficient or not)? Its mean is $3\lambda$, and I don't see that it has any other properties that would make it suitable as an estimator for $\lambda$.

Comment: Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset math on this site.

Comment: @joriki The question isn't about an estimator for $\lambda$.  It looks like a question about the distribution of a sum.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: That's because the OP fundamentally changed the question after I commented, without replying to my comment or marking the edit. The original question was about an estimator for $\lambda$, as you can see in [the edit history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2871375/revisions) you get when you click on the edit time stamp above.

Comment: @joriki  I get it.  It looks like he really wasn't sure at first what he wanted.  The question in its final form is straightforward.

Comment: Error in previous statement. It is not so straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The standard method to get the distribution for a sum of two independent random variables is convolution. For discrete variables this takes the form of a sum. For $X_1+2X_2=t$ an individual $(kth)$ term in the sum for $P(T=t)$ is $P(X_2=k)P(X_1=t-2k)$.  The upper limit on the sum is $N=\lfloor\frac{t}{2}\rfloor$.  Therefore $P(T=t)=e^{-2\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\frac{\lambda^{t-2k}}{(t-2k)!}=\lambda^te^{-2\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{\lambda^{-k}}{k!(t-2k)!}$.  Unfortunately this last sum doesn't seem to have a neat expression.